# Pandas group observations by region, but aggregate several regions together if the number of observations in a region is less than X?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am kind of new in Python, and english is not my first language, so I apologize for any unclear language.

I have a problem where I want to count observations by small geographical regions (they are identified by a number. Close geographical areas have numbers near each other. For eksample, area 0001 is close to 0002 which again is close to 0003). Some of these regions have very few observations and I want the observations of those regions to aggregate together with regions until they satisfy a number, say 5, observations per greater () region.

To illustrate:

Take the dataframe:

```
d = {'region': ['0001', '0001','0002','0002','0002','0002','0003','0003','0003','0003','0003','0003','0003','0003'], 
     'observation': ['A1', 'B45', 'B83578','L87846','I4536','J8659','H8756','G0853','P89058','A98','B89056980','U9690','Q9875','N896']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_grouped = df.groupby('region')['observation'].count()
print(df_grouped)
```

Output:

```
region
0001    2
0002    4
0003    8
Name: observation, dtype: int64
```

What I want is an output that looks something like this:

```
region
[0001,0002]    6
0003           8
Name: observation, dtype: int64
```

Does anyone have any idea where I should start to get something similar to my result? there are also other columns in the dataframe that I want to for example get median income for the regions (and the grouped regions), but I think once I know how to get the desired output over the rest should be more straight forward.

Thanks in advance for any answers :)

Comment: I think you're going to need two groupbys.  To do this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no easy vectorial way to compute a group with reset upon threshold. You need to use a loop. I am assuming that the regions are first sorted by geographical order:

```
group = []
i = 0
total = 0
for k, v in df_grouped.items():
    if total > 5:
        i += 1
        total = 0
    total += v
    group.append(i)
group

df_grouped.reset_index().groupby(group).agg({'region': list, 'observation': 'sum'})
```

Output:

```
         region  observation
0  [0001, 0002]            6
1        [0003]            8
```